Topology of parts with negative curvature and the topology of surface
Assuming $M$ be 2-dimensional compact Riemannian manifold, let
$$
M^-=\{x\in M: K(x)<0\}
$$
where $K(x)$ is the sectional curvature. Then, I guess:
(1) If $M^-$ homeomorphism to open ball, then $M$ is 2-sphere.
(2) If $M^-$ is simply connected, then  $M$ is 2-sphere.
Are they right?

Your guess is quite wrong, such $M$ can have any genus.

@MoisheKohan  I can't see it. Could you give a detail example, for example, the torus $T^2$, when it is flat, $M^-=\varnothing$, when it is standard torus in $R^3$, $M^-$ is not simply connected.

@MoisheKohan  I'm not dismissing you. I just want to know how you see it.

Start with a regular 4-gon in $S^2$ and glue its opposite faces by spherical isometries. The result is $T^2$ with a spherical metric that has one singular point $p$, with the total cone angle $>2\pi$. Then one can smooth out the singularity by replacing a metric ball neighborhood of $p$ with a suitable disk with a rotationally-invariant metric interpolating between the positive and negative curvature. This smoothing out construction is explained in various places, for instance in the paper by Gromov and Thurston on pinching constants of negatively curved manifolds.

@MoisheKohan  Thanks, I know so little. How many years did you take to be so good?
